# Show a list where min. number > 5 in worksheet forumula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to return a list with a given criteria

My current data looks like

```
      A        B
1   Anna       4  
2   Brad       6
3   Claire     2
4   Dan        5
4   Evie       2
```

I want to select those with a "score" of 4 or less, and sort them in order!

As such, I'd love to see the result like (note the different columns)

```
      D        E
1    Claire    2
2    Evie      2  
3    Anna      4
```

I do not want to use pivot tables. I'm trying to learn what is actually possible with worksheet functions.

Is what I want to achieve possible?

The rest of this post doesn't work - I just wanted to prove that I had tried

I've had a go at the first part (to get column D working) which is to match those with a score of less than 5

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4, SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4>4,ROW($B$1:$B$1)), ROW()))
```

This fails because Small appears to return the item that matches small, as such, my result won't include both Claire and Evie as they both have a score of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could use the `FILTER()` function along with `SORT()` to get the desired output:

Solution is based on :

> I want to select those with a "score" of 4 or less, and sort them in
> order!

---

[image]

---

```
=SORT(FILTER(A1:B5,B1:B5<=4),2)
```

---

Or, Using `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()`

[image]

---

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$5,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A$5)/($B$1:$B$5<=4),ROW(A1)),)
```

---